# Azure Kubernetes Service and Istio : Enabling SSL for the application

Tags: azure, azure-aks, istio, istio-gateway

I have created an AKS cluster using the following Terraform code

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = var.virtual_network_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  address_space       = [var.virtual_network_address_prefix]

  subnet {
    name           = var.aks_subnet_name
    address_prefix = var.aks_subnet_address_prefix
  }

  subnet {
    name           = "appgwsubnet"
    address_prefix = var.app_gateway_subnet_address_prefix
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "kubesubnet" {
  name                 = var.aks_subnet_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_network.test]
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  name       = var.aks_name
  location   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  dns_prefix = var.aks_dns_prefix

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  http_application_routing_enabled = false

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = var.vm_user_name

    ssh_key {
      key_data = file(var.public_ssh_key_path)
    }
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name            = "agentpool"
    node_count      = var.aks_agent_count
    vm_size         = var.aks_agent_vm_size
    os_disk_size_gb = var.aks_agent_os_disk_size
    vnet_subnet_id  = data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet.id
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = local.client_id
    client_secret = local.client_secret
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "azure"
    dns_service_ip     = var.aks_dns_service_ip
    docker_bridge_cidr = var.aks_docker_bridge_cidr
    service_cidr       = var.aks_service_cidr
  }

  # Enabled the cluster configuration to the Azure kubernets with RBAC
  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control { 
    managed                     = var.azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control_managed
    admin_group_object_ids      = var.active_directory_role_based_access_control_admin_group_object_ids
    azure_rbac_enabled          = var.azure_rbac_enabled
  }

  oms_agent {
    log_analytics_workspace_id  = module.log_analytics_workspace[0].id
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    delete = "20m"
  }  

  depends_on = [data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet,module.log_analytics_workspace]
  tags       = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ra1" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = local.client_objectid
  depends_on = [data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet]
}
```

and followed the below steps to install the ISTIO as per the ISTIO documentation

```
#Prerequisites
helm repo add istio https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
helm repo update

#create namespace
kubectl create namespace istio-system

# helm install istio-base and istiod
helm install istio-base istio/base -n istio-system
helm install istiod istio/istiod -n istio-system --wait

# Check the installation status
helm status istiod -n istio-system

#create namespace and enable istio-injection for envoy proxy containers
kubectl create namespace istio-ingress
kubectl label namespace istio-ingress istio-injection=enabled

## helm install istio-ingress for traffic management
helm install istio-ingress istio/gateway -n istio-ingress --wait

## Mark the default namespace as istio-injection=enabled
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
```

and deployed the following app and service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: httpbin
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  labels:
    app: httpbin
    service: httpbin
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: httpbin
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: httpbin
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: httpbin
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/kennethreitz/httpbin
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: httpbin
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and added the secrets like mentioned below

> kubectl create -n istio-system secret tls httpbin-credential  --key=example_certs1/httpbin.example.com.key   --cert=example_certs1/httpbin.example.com.crt

and Gateway installed like mentioned below

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingress # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: httpbin-credential # must be the same as secret
    hosts:
    - httpbin.example.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  hosts:
  - "httpbin.example.com"
  gateways:
  - mygateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /status
    - uri:
        prefix: /delay
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8000
        host: httpbin
```

and updated the host file like mentioned below

[image]

However I can't access the Application

[image]

**Note:** I can access an another application that doesn't use SSL

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `istioctl analyze`? I'm assuming it is saying that it can't find the `credentialName` "httpbin-credential". The next thing to do is see what's happening with the certificate. You can do that with `istioctl proxy-config secret -n istio-ingress <ingress_pod_name>`. What is the `STATUS` of the `kubernetes://httpbin-credential` cert chain? Is it set as `VALID`?

Comment: Actually re-reading your post, I don't think you're using the CA cert when making the request through your browser (unless there's some other config we're missing). Did you try with `curl` from this reference? https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/